# Delegate func in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, delegates, func

I have a problem with optimizing  my code).
Is it possible to create a method that returns necessary outerKeySelector (i => i.ItemId1, i => i.ItemId2 etc.) as func for Join that depends from ItemType ?

Thanks!

```
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public long ItemId1 { get; set; }
        public long ItemId2 { get; set; }
        public long ItemId3 { get; set; }
        public long ItemId4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class IdModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ItemType
    {
        Item1,
        Item2,
        Item3,
        Item4
    }
```

I believe it could be much shorter)

```
private static IEnumerable<IdModel> GetResult(IEnumerable<ItemModel> itemList, IEnumerable<IdModel> idList, ItemType itemType)
        {
            return itemType switch
            {
                ItemType.Item1 => itemList.Join(idList,
                    i => i.ItemId1,
                    j => j.Id,
                    (i, j) => new IdModel()
                    {
                        Id = j.Id,
                        Quantity = j.Quantity
                    }),
                ItemType.Item2 => itemList.Join(idList,
                    i => i.ItemId2,
                    j => j.Id,
                    (i, j) => new IdModel()
                    {
                        Id = j.Id,
                        Quantity = j.Quantity
                    })
            };
        }
```

Comment: Best way is to use IEqualityComparer<T> Interface.  See :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest shorter is necessarily more optimal, but I sometimes prefer shorter to more verbose anyway.

With a little preparation work creating a `Dictionary<>` to map `ItemType`s to accessor delegates, you can remove your `switch` expression.

```
private static Dictionary<ItemType, Func<ItemModel,long>> ItemIdAccessMap = new() {
    { ItemType.Item1, (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId1 },
    { ItemType.Item2, (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId2 },
    { ItemType.Item3, (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId3 },
    { ItemType.Item4, (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId4 },
};
```

I prefer reversing the order of the `Join` since you are throwing away the `itemList` members that match anyway.

```
private static IEnumerable<IdModel> GetResult(IEnumerable<ItemModel> itemList, IEnumerable<IdModel> idList, ItemType itemType)
    => idList.Join(
                itemList,
                id => id.Id,
                ItemIdAccessMap[itemType],
                (id, item) => id
       );
```

If you are concerned with having all `ItemType` members being handled, you could use Reflection to create the delegates dynamically, at the expense of some startup runtime.

Comment: Why don't you want to use switch expression? 

       `private static Func<ItemModel, long> GetSelector(ItemType itemType)
        {
            return itemType switch
            {
                ItemType.Item1 => (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId1,
                ItemType.Item2 => (ItemModel item) => item.ItemId2,
            };
        }`

Comment: @A1exZr A `switch` expression would work fine in this case, but I think using a `Dictionary<>` works better in the case where the values are not contiguous. I also think it scales better for a large number of cases. It also allows for creating at runtime based on the `enum` and property name patterns.